# return enum name base value

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, enums

I have a enum

```
public enum citys
{
       a=1,
       b=1,
       c=1,
       d=2,
       e=2,
       f=2,
};
```

And I want return `Name` base on value.For example, in `foreach return Enum.GetNames` that `Value =1`

```
 result --> a,b,c
 foreach return Enum.GetNames that Value =2
 result --> d,e,f
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can use `Enum.GetNames` in combination with `Enum.Parse` - it's not something I'd *like* to do, but it works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public enum City
{
       a=1,
       b=1,
       c=1,
       d=2,
       e=2,
       f=2,
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Or GetNames((City) 2)
        foreach (var name in GetNames(City.a))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetNames<T>(T value) where T : struct
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(T))
                   .Where(name => Enum.Parse(typeof(T), name).Equals(value));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could get the fields with reflection:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetNames<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    return typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                    .Where(f => f.GetValue(null).Equals(value))
                    .Select(f => f.Name);
}
```

It's not really clear whether using an enum is a good design for what you want to achieve though - what's the real goal here? Perhaps you should use a lookup instead?